# Can't use array in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to initialize an array, set it to hold other variables, and then use it whenever the user presses a button on my form. When I try to use the array in the button1_Click class, it doesn't recognize it and says it doesn't exist in the current setting.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string activity;
        int activityTime;
        bool enteredInt = false;

        //initializes variables used to store activities
        string activity1 = "";
        string activity2 = "";
        string activity3 = "";
        string activity4 = "";
        string activity5 = "";


        //intitializes variables used to store activity times
        int activityTime1 = 0;
        int activityTime2 = 0;
        int activityTime3 = 0;
        int activityTime4 = 0;
        int activityTime5 = 0;

        int i;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] activities = { activity1, activity2, activity3, activity4, activity5 };
            int[] activityTimes = { activityTime1, activityTime2, activityTime3, activityTime4, activityTime5 };

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enteredInt = Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out activityTime);

            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && enteredInt == true)
            {
                activity = textBox1.Text;
                activityTime = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid activity and time.");
            }

            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                if (activity==activities[i])
                {
                    activity += activities[i];
                    i = 5;
                }
            }



        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I just really need it answered.

Comment: It displays the error as '"The name 'activities' does not exist in the current context" at "if(activity==activities[i])" and "activity+=activities[i];"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define  int[]activityTimes as a global variable, put it outside

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string activity;
    int activityTime;
    bool enteredInt = false;

    //initializes variables used to store activities
    string activity1 = "";
    string activity2 = "";
    string activity3 = "";
    string activity4 = "";
    string activity5 = "";


    //intitializes variables used to store activity times
    int activityTime1 = 0;
    int activityTime2 = 0;
    int activityTime3 = 0;
    int activityTime4 = 0;
    int activityTime5 = 0;

    int i;
    string[] activities=new string[length];


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: string[] activities=new string[5];

Comment: the length means distribute how long just you want

Comment: That's not a "global variable", it's an instance variable. Each instance of your Form1 class will get one of those. All instance methods will have access to it.